# Is there a way to output resources requested and used by SLURM job?

Tags: resources, slurm

I'm just moving to a new cluster and I was wondering if there is a way for SLURM to output a list of resources used in a similar way that PBS does (cputime, memory used, etc.), in hopes that I can benchmark my jobs and can make better use of the cluster. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `squeue`, `sqcct`, and `sinfo` commands.  They have a plethora of options that can show you everything about your jobs.  For my cluster, I have the following aliases:

```
alias si='sinfo -o "%.11N %.11T %.14C %.7m %.8d %20E" --Node'
alias sq='squeue --format="%.9i %22j %8u %8T %.7M %.13l %6D %20R %C"'
```